# Installing modules for Bitnami Django Stack

Tags: python, django

I have installed Bitnami Django Stack on my windows machine. Now I have to extend an existing Django project. When I tried to run the project using **manage.py runserver** it gave me modules error. So I installed all the required modules in **C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps** folder.

Now When I run the manage.py runserver command it is giving me attribute errors. These errors are related to installed modules.

My question is that How can I verify If I have installed the modules correctly?

Comment: Can you paste errors content here?

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ImageField'.

ImageField is used from sorl.thumbnail module

Comment: And traceback? Because this error can be anything- and without context it's guessing rather than answering...

Comment: Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 88, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)

Comment: File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\core\management\base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\core\management\validation.py", line 36, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\db\models\loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()

Comment: File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\db\models\loading.py", line 61, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\db\models\loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)

Comment: File "...\core\models.py", line 34, in <module>
    class Profile(models.Model):
  File "...\core\models.py", line 39, in Profile
    photo = thumbnail.ImageField(upload_to=profile_photo_path, blank=True, null=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ImageField'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import ImageField from sorl.thumbnail- not import thumbnail module.

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
#...
class Profile(models.Model):
    photo = ImageField(..)
```

[Example in documentation](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html#model-examples)